# Need more Accumulo examples implemented in java

Tags: java, accumulo

I am new to Accumulo. I have configured Hadoop, Zookeeper, Accumulo.
      I also went through the Apache Accumulo wiki and accumulo.apache.org
      but they have less number of examples that reveals less information from 
     development perspective. Can Anyone suggest where resources or PDFs for Accumulo
    I can found ?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the set of examples at http://accumulo.apache.org/1.5/examples/?  Many of these examples correspond to one or more Java files in the examples/simple module in each Accumulo tarball, or you can [browse them here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=accumulo.git;a=tree;f=examples/simple/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/examples/simple;h=d323712f6eda15a0794eac96ac11e8c5428a4cd3;hb=5266a71be09772d58a3cce223fdc61192097c339).